# Redirect to a different page if "webpage not found"?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, web, alert

Is there a way to check if a connection is not available and show an alert (or whatever content) before the "webpage not available" browser message appears, or add a redirect to another page if the "webpage is not found"?

Comment: Do you have some source code to provide?

Comment: If you have a webserver like apache this can be configured in the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a call and check the return status with AJAX. Then based on the status code such as 200,404, you can decide what you want to do. This can be done easier with jQuery.ajax() method if you use jQuery.

With jQuery

```
$.ajax({
 statusCode: {
  404: function() {
    alert( "page not found" );
  }
 }
});
```

Pure JS:

```
function checkUrl(url) {
    var request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }

    if (request) {
            request.open("GET", url);
            if (request.status == 200) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
```

}

Resource:

With pure js,
https://www.igotitworking.com/problem/view/69/

Comment: is this cross-browser? otherwise looking at the code it seems like exactly what I was trying to code up myself! Thanks alot!!!

Comment: Yes. It also checks for activeXObject which is for IE. But I suggest you use jQuery ajax for better cross-browser implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check before the page was loaded obviously so you'd something like this should work...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://domainname.com/pagename.php',
    success: function() {
        // no 404 error
    },
    error: function() {
        // error in HEAD (404 etc)
    }
});
```